# mvc 4 reusable controls in one page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I am new with MVC framework. When I was using Web form, the user control can be assigned parameter in the Page and can be Generated unique ID in the Page. Even though you implemented the control more than one time in the same page.

In MVC framework, Partial View is the only way to implement reusable control. I got some problems below.

How to Implement same reusable control more than once in the same page with different parameters.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470827(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: I know RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial can pass different ViewData, but if the partial view is implementing some JavaScripts/Jquery, it would generate issue with Id in the same page.

Answer (score 1):

> I know RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial can pass different
>   ViewData, but if the partial view is implementing some
>   JavaScripts/Jquery, it would generate issue with Id in the same page

You can differentiate that id within passed models . you can put for example some unique member for that model and use inside partial view :

```
<p id="element@(Model.unique.ToString()) ></p>
```

***Or avoid id selection inside jscript at all. for example use class selectors***

Comment: It is a good idea, however, if you are using someting like @Html.DropDownListFor, how to generate the unique ID for the dropdown??

Comment: @user2376512 mmm on that case think you should write that helper by yourself . you can use mvc source code or  for example here is implementation for linkedlist http://kruisit.nl/articles/asp.net-mvc-linked-dropdown/  ..but if it be template then better avoid using templates